Apache POI, export empty excel after upgrading from 3.17 to 4.1.2
Recently, I have updated the Apache POI from 3.17 to 4.1.2 because of the vulnerability name XSSFExportToXml XXE, namely "CVE-2019-12415". Fortunately, I don't have to rewrite any code. But the excel exmported are all empty. Maybe I should ask for help here before I have to read the official documents for such a specific problem. Is there anyone who has faced the same problem? Thank you if you can tell me about how you solve it.

Does migrating to v5.x help?

Its generally because there is some error thrown somewhere. Can you check if you are somehow suppressing any error by catching it and not doing anything else?
If you are confident that this is not the case, you can try to replace current logic for writing with some very small content and see if its working. If not, then you can share the simplified snippet here which will help us to help you.
